# Possible to get varying sizes of Tumblr theme options uploaded images?

Tags: image, themes, tumblr

In using Tumblr theme tags, you can use `{PortraitURL-16}` or `{PortraitURL-128}` to get a 16x16px or 128x128px (respectively) portrait image URL. Similarly you can use `{PhotoURL-500}` to get a 500px wide URL to that image in a photo post.

I'm wondering if it is at all possible to do the same thing (specify a dimension value) for custom uploaded images in my Tumblr theme. For example, I use `{image:Avatar}`, and if someone were to upload a 1280 pixel-wide photo, I'm still going to be display it at 60x60px. Is there any way to specify `{image:Avatar-60}` so I'm not loading a huge image on every page load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Afaik, no. Images are processed in three different ways on Tumblr.

#### Photo / Photoset / Panoramic Post

When creating a new Photo / Photoset post any images added, Tumblr will process, and create multiple copies at various sizes. You can then retrieve a specific size by using the appropriate theme operators:

```
{PhotoURL-HighRes}
{PhotoURL-500}
{PhotoURL-400}
{PhotoURL-250}
{PhotoURL-100}
{PhotoURL-75sq}
```

#### Theme Assets

You can also upload an image whilst customising a theme, via the customisation page. Unlike Photo / Photoset Post, these images are processed and retain their original size and multiple sized versions aren't created.

#### Post Body / Caption

Finally you can upload an image whilst adding content to the post body / caption. These images are processed and capped at 500px high / wide.

Hope that helps!